# Steam won't start on Linux Mint 20.3

Tags: linux-mint, steam, nvidia

On Linux Mint 20.3 Steam won't launch but there is no error.
After uninstalled, purged and reinstalled Steam it launches correctly but only until next reboot. Reinstall after every boot is not a fine workaround :)

Notice that I also have Lutris installed and it now provides his own version of Steam, can be there a conflict ?

Some bunch of useful informations :

```
uname -a
Linux julien-Nitro-5 5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
prime-select query
nvidia
```

```
nvidia-smi
Tue Jul 19 20:35:12 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.48.07    Driver Version: 515.48.07    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P8    10W /  N/A |    232MiB /  6144MiB |      7%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       876      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                113MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1331      G   cinnamon                           43MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2324      G   ...357144633483984322,131072       71MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
steam
steam.sh[3982]: Running Steam on linuxmint 20.3 64-bit
steam.sh[3982]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[4133]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[3982]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
```

Comment: Since last update nvidia drivers are now 515.65.01 but Steam still not launching

Comment: I'm able to launch Steam throught the terminal so it seems to be Cinnamon related

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss some graphic-driver releated packages, try to install:

```
libnvidia-gl-515
```

If it does not resolve your problem respond to me in comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was miss it but it didn't help even after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem with the Linux Mint 21.1 on my notebook. In my case, the problem started after I changed the GPU mode to `on-demand` (I have a Nvidia dGPU) with `sudo prime-select on-demand`. Even when I reinstalled Steam, after reboot, Steam still wouldn't start.
However, if I switched back to `intel` or `nvidia`, Steam started normally.

In the `on-demand` context, I'm doing the same workaround as you, starting Steam through the `terminal` or through `Lutris` (in this case, it uses my default Steam installation), after kill it in the process list. I also pass the `RENDER_OFFLOAD` and the `VENDOR_LIBRARY` environment variables in `cli`.

```bash
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia steam
```

As you mentioned, the app also doesn't open through `Cinammon` for some reason. Even after exporting the environment variables in the Steam startup script: `sudo xed $(command -v steam)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, running steam via terminal

```
steam
steam.sh[3982]: Running Steam on linuxmint 20.3 64-bit
steam.sh[3982]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[4133]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[3982]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
```

and.. nothing happened.

Previously I had `nvidia-driver-535` driver installed. So I purged it
`$ sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-535`
and restart, somehow steam launched as expected.